# What is the best method to extract a subject from a Greenscreen?

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, background, backdrops

I am searching for a better method to cut people out of my greenscreen backdrop ...
The main problem is the hair ... 
Actually I use the freeware [Easygreenscreen](http://www.photoshopgreenscreen.com/) Photoshop action
I also know the super-long and time-consuming Tutorials on Youtube ...

Does anybody have an idea for a comfortable method like Easygreenscreen? Or has anyone used the "pro" version of that programm?

Second thing, does anyone know some good free backdrop images? I haven't found any useful backdrops.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site.  You will get better answers if you ask one question at a time. Would you mind asking about backdrops separately?

Comment: More often than not the problems with greenscreen extraction can be addressed by taking better greenscreen photographs. If the subject and the greenscreen are lit properly extraction becomes much easier. Would you care to describe your setup and maybe show one of your shots and the extraction you made of it?

Comment: Sub-pixel details and translucent elements are always going to be a problem -- changing the lighting to make the replacement/removal key chroma range smaller isn't going to help with that.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to go for something more versatile than chromakey software if you can. If you're using Photoshop, then a plugin like Topaz Labs Remask 3.2 or OnOne Perfect Mask will both fill the chromakey bill perfectly (both will let you deal with transparency/translucency and small details perfectly) AND will allow you to do extraction/replacement in images that weren't shot on a green or blue screen with only a little more difficulty.

They're not entirely automatic (nor are they free after the trial has elapsed) but with a chromakey image, it only takes a few seconds (with a bit of practice) to do a perfect extraction with the green removed from hair, transparent fabrics, and so on -- and without having to worry about your subject having key-out colours somewhere. I've had little difficulty extracting a subject or subject grouping out of any image using a good masking package (I currently use the Topaz product) unless there's a sort of camouflage effect going on (where everything in the picture is almost the same colour and texture). If you have to spend money on software, it might as well be spent on something that can do more than one trick.